# While Loop just runs one time

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

my problem ist that my while loop just runs one time when I run it. Here is my code. I would be very thankful if someone would check it and maybe look for other faults (i'm new at programming java!)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Program {

    boolean exit;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField title;
    JButton start;
    JButton stop;
    long x;


    public Program() {

        frame = new JFrame("Überlast your PC");
        panel = new JPanel();
        title = new JTextField("Überlast your PC v1.0");
        start = new JButton("Start");
        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        x = 1;
        exit = false;

        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            exit = true;

        }});

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            panel.remove(start);
            panel.add(stop);
            frame.repaint();
            frame.revalidate();
            start.setForeground(Color.red);
            while(x <= 9223372036854775807L) {

                System.out.println(x * x);
                x++;

                if (exit = true) {                    
                    break;                        
                }                    
            }

        }});

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(title);
        panel.add(start);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(150,100);
        title.setEditable(false);
        start.setForeground(Color.green);
        stop.setForeground(Color.red);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you hard coding that ugly long literal?

Comment: After fixing the obvious error, it will be an **infinite loop**.

Comment: Your code would be clearer if you use Long.MAX_VALUE instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
 if(exit = true) {
      break;
 }
```

should be

```
 if(exit == true) {
      break;
  }
```

Or even simpler, just use

```
 if(exit){
   break;
 }
```

`exit=true` assigns **true** to exit, thus the if condition is true thus it breaks outta of the loop.

As @jlordo pointed, even after fixing the error its an infinite loop.

Comment: Is nobody else aware of that infinite loop?

Comment: @jlordo i just realized, yeah it is an infinite loop

Comment: @jlordo Wouldn't `for(;;){}` or `while(true){}` be more readable alternatives?

Comment: @WilliamShatner.. I think, OP probably need `while (exit)`, and change the `exit` somewhere in the loop.

Comment: @RohitJain in which case he doesnt even need a break .. :P

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR.. Yeah, right. He need to change `exit` somewhere in the code. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(exit = true)
```

This is the first problem. The above if condition will always be true. You need to do comparison instead of assignment. In fact you should not do comparison for boolean variable. Just use: -

```
if (exit)
```

Secondly, you are not changing your `exit` anywhere in your while loop, so, it doesn't make sense for using it as a exit condition.

And you don't need to hard code the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`. You already have that constant defined. Now, even if you get through that problem of `if`, you will face the problem of `infinite loop`. See below how: -

```
// Your below while loop is `infinite`
// every long value will satisfy this condition
while(x <= Long.MAX_VALUE) {  // Don't hard code max long value

      System.out.println(x * x);
      x++;

      // You are not changing `exit` anywhere, so this check is absurd.   
      if (exit) {  
          break;                        
      }                    
}
```

---

**What probably you want: -**

Probably you want to run your loop infinitely, until your `exit` value if `false`. In that case, just use `while (true)`. And change the value of `exit` somewhere in your loop.

In fact, if you are using `exit` as exit criteria, I would change your `while` loop to: -

```
while (exit) {
    System.out.println(x * x);

    if (someCondition) {
        exit = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think his intentions are for his stop button to exit the infinite loop.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR.. :)

Comment: Semantically, shouldn't that be `while (!exit) {...` (with the condition flipped)?  Or really, probably `while (run) {...`?  And if he flags the boolean with `volatile`, wouldn't it work the way he wanted?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse.. On Semantics, yeah it should be like that. But I have just mapped the meaning used in OP code in mine.

Answer (score 2):

you are using

```
if(exit = true) {
```

instead of

```
if(exit == true) {
```

or even better

```
if (exit) {
```

But when you fix it, you will have an **infinite loop**, because all `long` values are smaller than `9223372036854775807`, which is the the highest value long can have.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line:

```
if(exit = true)
```

You are **assigning** `true` to `exit` here. Use `==` for comparing values:

```
if(exit == true)
```

And in the case of boolean values, you don't need to compare it to `true` at all. Write it like this:

```
if(exit)
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (exit = true)` will set the value exit to true. You need to compare using `==`